i have confusion about typescript in react
i am beginner to typescript,Is the following approach correct for typescript?
my parent component
interface MailDetailsProps {
  mailId?: string;
}

interface MailPopup {
  open?: boolean;
  width?: string;
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
  title?: string;
}

const MailDetails: React.FC<MailDetailsProps> = ({ mailId }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [mailPopup, setMailPopup] = useState<MailPopup>({});

  return (
    <>
      <MailDetailsPopup mailPopup={mailPopup} setMailPopup={setMailPopup} />
    </>
  );
};

MailDetails.propTypes = {
  mailId: PropTypes.string
};

export default MailDetails;

my child component
interface MailDetailsPopupProps {
  mailPopup: any;
  setMailPopup: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>;
}

const MailDetailsPopup: React.FC<MailDetailsPopupProps> = ({ mailPopup, setMailPopup }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [emailOpen, setEmailOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
  
  );
};

export default MailDetailsPopup;

I am not sure about define mailPopup: any.Because i already defined in my parent component.

I suggest working through a good tutorial or book on TypeScript. "I am not sure about define mailPopup: any. Because i already defined in my parent component." If your component expects the mailPopup prop to receive something matching the MailPopup interface, then its type should be MailPopup, not any. There are very few correct use cases for any in modern TypeScript code. (I think some would argue there aren't any uses cases for it anymore now that we have unknown, but I wouldn't go that far. But then again, I'm only "so" good at TS, so...)

"I am not sure about define mailPopup: any.Because i already defined in my parent component." define the type in another file, and import it into both the components.

First:
Don't use ...more in interface.
second:
You have mailPopup declared as any in child component so what do you expect ?
export interface and type it properly.
interface MailDetailsPopupProps {
  mailPopup: MailPopup; // exported from parent component
  setMailPopup: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<MailPopup>>;
}


"Don't use ...more in interface" that isn't literal code, OP is just saying they don't want to type out all the properties of that interface. The second half of what you said is correct but would land better if you actually wrote out an example of how to do that...

My bad, still second point is the answer.

@TomasLachmann Yes, but just saying that as briefly as you did is kinda like telling OP "the answer to your question is the answer to your question". Honestly, if a question has a 5 word answer it probably should be closed rather than answered to begin with, but I think this question can be salvaged if you put some example code in your answer.

I exported MailPopup interface and used in child, thanks for help
